# How do I set up a BitTornado tracker?

Tags: bittorrent

I would like to setup a BitTornado tracker for a local network. At the moment I am using OpenBitTorrent as my tracker but this seems strange as I don't want to do this over the net and I'm not sure how secure or legal it is.

The "server" is running Bodhi Linux.

I found a how-to on TuxCoder using this command to start the tracker

```
bttrack --port 6969 --dfile ~/.bttrack/dstate --logfile ~/.bttrack/tracker.log --nat_check 0 --scrape_allowed full
```

However I get back a deprecation warning:

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/BitTornado/__init__.py:8: DeprecationWarning: the sha module is deprecated; use the hashlib module instead
  from sha import sha
**warning** could not redirect stdout to log file:  <type 'exceptions.IOError'>
```

It may be that there is a better tracker out there. I'm not an expert, which is why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply a warning, you can just ignore it. There is a command line flag to python to make it ignore that class of warnings: `-W ignore::DeprecationWarning` (it's ignored by default starting at version 2.7)

Personally I'm still using bttrack even though it's getting old and does not support the latest improvements to the Bittorrent protocol: it's efficient, easy to use and reliable. I've got a couple of trackers and seeders up and running to support a Linux distribution.

Comment: Thanks zarkdav running like a charm. Which distro if you don't mind?

Comment: You're welcome Allan. I've been using it for Jolicloud.